# Dialog - Opening a closed dialog without creating a new dialog

Tags: java, dialog, swt

This is a much simpler question.

```
private static AplotBaseDialog dlg; 


public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
  if (dlg == null){
     try {
          Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event).getShell();
          dlg = new AplotBaseDialog(shell, session);  
     }
     catch {
     }
     dlg.open();
     return null;
 }
```

Ok the above code checks and see if dlg is null.  If it is null then create a new dialog.
Then it opens the dialog.

This works when dlg is null.  But if dlg is not null, I get a error at the line dlg.open().
The error is pointing to this code in the dialog class

```
  @Override
  protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
     Control contents = super.createContents(parent); <==== Right Here
     setTitle("Title");
     setMessage("Message");
     if (image != null) {
        setTitleImage(image);
     }
     return contents;
  }
```

So my question is how can I open the dialog when dlg != null?

***EDIT***
Adding some of the error message

[image]

line 110 in AplotBaseDialog

```
Control contents = super.createContents(parent);
```

line 48 in AplotDialogHandler

```
dlg.open();
```

Comment: If `dlg` is not `null`, your code should do nothing, since you check for `null`. Moreover, post the error. We aren't psychic ;)

Comment: I will post the error.  The user is allowed close the dailog box, but the main application shell is still valid.  This is so the user can close my application's dialog so they can easily use the Main Application's GUI.  When they are ready to use my application again, they click the menu again and it opens the dialog with the data they have already had added earlier in the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
>
> ...
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.setImage(Label.java:337)

JavaDoc of [`Label`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Label.html) tells you the following:

> IllegalArgumentException -
>
> ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT - if the image has been disposed

So, it seems like you already disposed the image you are trying to set.

---

There are two solutions for this:

1. Wait with the disposal of the image until your main application is closed.
2. Dispose the image when the dialog is closed, but create a new one, when you reopen it.